# A relation between projections

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $A$ be a vn-algebra. Let $e,p$ and $q$ be projections in $A$. Suppose that $p\leq q$. True or false?

$$q\wedge e-p\wedge e\leq q-p$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

False in general. Take $A=M_2(\mathbb C) $, $$q=I,\ \ \ p=\begin {bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end {bmatrix},\ \ \ \ e=\begin {bmatrix}1/2&1/2\\1/2&1/2\end {bmatrix}.
$$
Then $e\wedge p=0$, so $$q\wedge e-p\wedge e=e\not\leq q-p. $$

Comment: Nice example, Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome.  If you like the answer, please upvote (not a big deal, but it is how the site works, and I have to admit I don't like seeing "zero votes" next to my answer).